# jQuery/Ajax - How to pass plain text into C# (PUT method) with single argument?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that uses a $.ajax call to a web api url called /api/show in C#.  When I run the project I am unable to get string value on the second body of code to be anything other than null. I am explicitly passing in showsList to the put method in the server controller (showsList is as an example, "show1, show2, show3") which is a comma separated plain text value.

How can I get the comma separated text into the PUT method that has a single argument on the 2nd code segment?

Do I need to totally avoid using $.ajax for this purpose?  If so I need to determine which other jQuery method I would need to call.

Client Code:

```
function addShows() {
        var selectedShows = [];
        var showList = "";
        selectedShows = getSelectedShows();
        showList = selectedShows.join(", ");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/show",
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "text",
            data: showList,
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('email', $("#email").val());
            },
            success: function (status) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Controller PUT Method Code:

```cs
// PUT api/show/5
public void Put([FromBody]string value)
{
      string email = Request.Headers.GetValues("email").FirstOrDefault().Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ').Trim();
      DAL.DAL.addShowsByUserEmail(email, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `$.ajax` makes the most sense here - considering you're not receiving data back from the server. `$.post` would probably make more sense. However, `$.ajax` should work.

A couple issues with how you currently have it set up. First, the URL appears to be pointing incorrectly to your method. It should be `url: "/api/show/Put"`, and then `type:` should be `type:POST` - this doesn't point to the method, but instead signifies that the browser should execute a HTTP post. If you are receiving null in your method, try explicitly declaring an object for the `data:` parameter: `data: {value: showList}` - note that the parameter name, `value`, corresponds to the argument of your method.

```
function addShows() {
        var selectedShows = [];
        var showList = "";
        selectedShows = getSelectedShows();
        showList = selectedShows.join(", ");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/show/Put",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {value:showList},
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('email', $("#email").val());
            },
            success: function (status) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Your method should then look something like:

```
[HTTPPost]
public void Put(string value)
{
      string email = Request.Headers.GetValues("email").FirstOrDefault().Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ').Trim();
      DAL.DAL.addShowsByUserEmail(email, value);
}
```

Let me know if this fixes your issues.

Comment: I did use a json instead of text but with $.ajax.  The key modification was to add a model in my project with a property public string list {get; set;} which is the same name as the json key.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addShows() {
        var selectedShows = [];
        var showList = "";
        selectedShows = getSelectedShows();
        showList = selectedShows.join(", ");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/show",
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "json",
            data:JSON.stringify(showList),
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('email', $("#email").val());
            },
            success: function (status) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Turns out I had to send the showList as json. More specifically as {"list": showList}.  I did not use data:JSON.stringify(showList) but I added a model called UserShows with a property of type string called list to match the JSON key.